# Which coordinate do sceneRect and boundingRect work on?

Tags: qt

According to the Qt's documentation, the QPainter is working on the logical coordinate.

But how about the sceneRect of the QGraphicsScene and the boundingRect of the QGraphicsItem?

Are they working on the logical coordinates or the physical coordinates?

If it's on the logical coordinates, is there any functions like the `QPainter::setWindow` for them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A GraphicsItem's boundingRect defines its area in local coordinates; local to the item. So, an item derived from QGraphicsItem, which overrides its paint function, can draw the item's area by drawing its boundingRect: -

```
painter->drawRect(boundingRect());
```

The sceneRect of a QGraphicsItem is the item's boundingRect translated into scene coordinates.

So, for example, from this skeleton class:

```
class MyItem : public QGraphicsItem
{
    public: 
        QRectF boundingRect() const { return m_boundingRect; }

    private:
        QRectF m_boundingRect = QRectF(-10, -10, 20, 20);
}
```

The bounding rect is defined such that its centre lies at (0,0) in local coordinates.

If we add it to a scene, at position (0,0), calling the item's sceneBoundingRect function will return the same coordinates.

Now, if we move the item 5 units in the x: -

```
pItem->setPos(5, 0);
```

The boundingRect returns the same local coordinates, but its sceneBoundingRect will return its position in the scene; (-5, -10, 20, 20), with these being (x, y, width,height).

If an item is a child of another item, then this will be taken into account, as setting its position sets it relative to its parent or, in the case of no parent, will set it as the coordinates in the scene.

Therefore, calling an item's boundingRect() function, will always return the same coordinates, regardless of where the item resides in the scene, but it's sceneBoundingRect will return scene coordinates; where it resides in the scene.

> If it's on the logical coordinates, is there any functions like the QPainter::setWindow for them?

Yes, the QPainter has its own transformation system, which allows you to perform actions such rotation or scaling before drawing. You can read more about its coordinate transformation in the [Qt documentation for QPainter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#coordinate-transformations)

Answer (score 1):

`sceneRect()` and `boundingRect()` work in the scene coordinates (logical coordinates). However if you draw in a scene the QPainter also resides in these cordinates, it does not know the physical coordinates.

You probably want to use `setWorldTransform()` instead of `setWindow()`. While `setWindow()` might still work as intended, it does not support floating point coordinates, which is what you get from `boundingRect()` and friends.

To get back to physical coordinates from the `QGraphicsScene`, you can use `QGraphicsView::mapToGlobal()`.

Comment: But there is no such functions like setWorldTransform for the QGraphicsScene isn't it? And how could I set the transform matrix from scene to view? I could only set its sceneRect

Comment: `setWorldTransform()` is a `QPainter` method. I understood your question wrong. I don't know if there is such functionality in `QGraphicsScene`, but you can set the sceneRect to match the physical coordinates and use `setTransform()` on all items in the scene (and `setWorldTransform()` on the QPainter for drawing the background).